# Joining sales, product and referrer data using sql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

In a nutshell, I have three tables:

Products: belongs to many Purchases

Purchases: has one Product
- has one Referrer
- Relevant fields: price

Referrer: belongs to one Purchase
Relevant fields: Referrer.url

All tables have the obvious/necessary foreign keys.

In english, I need a result like this: Give me the total number (COUNT) of purchases and total sales amount (SUM) for each Referrer

I have tried many different sql queries but it's been driving me nust all afternoon. Any ideas? :-)

Thanks!

--------UPDATE-----

Thanks to Suing this was the resulting sql:

```
SELECT 
referer_trackings.cookie_first_url,
sum(purchases.price) AS sales, 
count(purchases.id) AS volume
FROM purchases
JOIN referer_trackings 
ON referer_trackings.trackable_id = purchases.id 
JOIN items
ON purchases.item_id = items.id
WHERE items.seller_id = '39'
AND referer_trackings.trackable_type = 'Purchase'
AND purchases.workflow_state = 'payment_successful'
GROUP BY referer_trackings.cookie_first_url
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GROUP BY

```
Select 
    sum(purchases.price) as totalAmount, 
    count(purchases.id) as totalCount,
    referrer.url
from Purchases
join Referrer 
    on referrer.url = purchases.url
Group by referrer.url
```